# How to remove duplicate words within columns using group_concat?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with records in TableA.ColumnA like this:

```
New York City
New York
New Rochelle
York Town
```

I am doing

> Select group_concat(ColumnA SEPARATOR ';') from TableA

but naturally end up with;

```
New York City; New York; New Rochelle; York Town
```

when what I am looking for is:

```
New; York; City; Rochelle; Town
```

In other words I want each word in each columnA to compare to each other words in ColumnA and remove any matching words so I end up with no duplicate 'keywords'.

Can I do this somehow in the `group_concat` or is there some process I need to run prior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way assuming your mySql supports *json_table* is to convert the strings to a json array and split into rows, then you can aggregate the distinct list:

```
select group_concat(words separator '; ') result
from (
  select distinct words
  from tableA t
  join json_table(
    replace(json_array(t.columnA), ' ', '","'),
    '$[*]' columns (words varchar(50) path '$')
  ) j
)t
```

See [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd5fa9d8a57174cd9036ca196c6631f2)

Comment: My version does not but the above is powerful and useful enough to make the hassle (?) of upgrading to MySql 8 worth it thank you.

Comment: You can do basically the same in 5.7 but it's just more faff, you'll need a numbers table and substr string splitty stuff.